# Replace weak symbol by adding additional object file

Tags: linker, embedded

I'm writing some firmware for a project where I wanted to include some debug information into the actual image file, so the fault handler in the firmware can produce some more detailed output. Using DWARF information for this is not an option due to size constraints, but doing some compromises I got the required information down to an acceptable level (how exactly not relevant here, assume binary blob). The problem now is: I can only generate those debug information once I produced a linked firmware image, but I need to add in those information into the firmware for them to be accessible. For this I reserved two weak symbols in the linker script (PROVIDED as 0) in their own section (.dbgsym), if no debug information is included. I'm now looking for a reproducible way to re-link the firmware image to include the additional information (available as a compiled object file containing these symbols in the right section), with the weak symbols replaced by the actual symbols provided in this extra object file. I'm using GCC from the GNU ARM toolchain, but am flexible in how exactly this post-processing step is done (as long it's easy to automate in a build system).

One option I came up is just doing the full linking step for the image again, but this relies on the linker being deterministic in the order that it places symbols into the final image, which I'd rather not be relying on.

As linking already uses a linker script I know that the additional data needs to be added at the end of the (bare) image file (plus updating of the places where the relevant pointers are stored). Thus I could just append the additional data and update these pointers in the binary. While this is certainly possible, this needs manually patching the firmware image where the linker could perfectly do its job.

I wonder how this is done in other places as adding in data to an existing (pre-linked) binary doesn't seem too strange or exotic.

P.S.: Target format is either ELF or raw binary image, with ELF being preferred.

Comment: Why *two* symbols?  start and end of the blob, or something more complicated?

Comment: Basically the start of two tables I need to maintain. But the exact details there should not change the general method to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but a much easier alternative solution:

1. Define a struct that contains the two (or more) values you need.
2. Declare an extern symbol which is of the struct type.
3. Access your values throughout your code using the members of the named struct.
4. Edit your main project linker script to define the struct symbol at the very end of the main image (possibly adjusting for alignment).
5. Write a tiny program to generate the struct blob and concatenate both it and the debug blob onto the main binary image.  This is simple enough to do in a scripting language.

Obviously if you only need a single pointer to the debug blob (not two values) then you don't even need the struct.

Comment: Doesn't this have 2 downsides?

1. It requires the symbol to be defined, thus debug information to be added in any case (something I'd keep the flexibility)

2. It forces this extra structure to be at the end of the (unmodified) image. (No real problem, but I'd prefer if those pointers could be referenced/stored anyway in the image).

Comment: Defining a symbol doesn't require debug information.  Just add debug_header = ALIGN(.) at the end of the linker script and the linker update any pointers in the code to point to the end of the image.  Yes this means it has to be located there.  Alternatively you could choose a fixed address, then you don't need to edit the linker script at all.

Comment: As far as I currently see this solution only seems to work with flat (-oformat=binary) files. Or is there existing tooling to achieve this for ELF files?

Comment: I have done something very similar to this with hex files before.  Hex has the small advantage over binary that the absolute address is in the file.  Other than that I think if you want to do it properly you need to use the linker or else find an elf editing library, either of which is going to take a lot more effort.